# Proposition 5.1.2 Markov Chain and Stochastic Stability: Tweedy

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

I am trying to understand the definition of an atom of a markov chain:

A set $\alpha\in \mathcal{B}(X)$ is called an atom if there exists a measure $\nu$ on $\mathcal{B}(X)$ such that
$$P(x,A)=\nu(A), \hspace{4mm} x\in \alpha$$

The way I was thinking about it is the one step transition probability is independent in this $\alpha$ set and is governed by the measure $\nu$ on the set A.

I was also trying to prove this proposition in the book as well:

If $L(x,A)>0$ for some state $x\in \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is an atom, then $\alpha\rightsquigarrow A$. Where $\alpha\rightsquigarrow A$ implies $\underset{y\in \alpha}{\text{inf}} L(y,A)\ge \delta$  for some $\delta>0$ and $L(y,A)$ is the probability of a finite return starting in y. The way I tried to show it was the following:

Since, $L(x,A)>0$ for some $x\in \alpha$ then there exists some $n$ such that $P^{n}(x,A)>0$. If I define the $n$ step markov chain $\Phi^{n}$ with transition probability $P^{n}$ then can define $P^{n}(x,A)=\nu(A)$ then to get the lower bound for any $x \in \alpha$

$$L(x,A)\ge P_x(\tau\le n)\ge P^{n}(x,A)=\nu(A)>0$$

If I use $\nu(A)$  as my $\delta$ then I am done. I just have to show that an atom in $\Phi$ is also an atom in $\Phi^{n}$ any ideas? And what is the best way to think about atoms? If my approach is completely wrong, how should I approach this.